# require.js fetching/loading order debug

Tags: requirejs, amd, javascript

Is there a tool or require.js function I can use to determine the fetching and loading order of my modules/traditional scripts?

For example,

a.js:

```
define(['b', 'c'], function(b,c){});
```

b.js:

```
define(['d'], function(d){});
```

and then a main.js that has

```
require(['a'], function(a){});
```

My assumption here is that:

1. a.js will be fetched first
2. b.js and c.js will be fetched second
3. d.js will be fetched last

and the modules will be loaded in the order of d -> b -> c -> a.  Or perhaps, d and c at the same time (since c has no dependencies like d) then b and finally a.

However, I'm never 100% certain my assumptions are correct.  I can refresh the page 100 times and verify I get no error, but I'm still paranoid that the 101st try will break.

AMD module developers, how do you debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fine control over the fetching order of modules, there's the [order plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#order).

You can also open the network console in Chrome/Firebug etc. to see the fetches take place.

But, your example is a fairly straightforward one that should have no problems either in the 101<sup>st</sup> iteration or the 1001<sup>st</sup>. I don't see anything to be concerned about or that needs debugging.

Comment: The docs for order plugin state that it shouldn't be necessary for modules that use define(), but there are cases where I have traditional scripts inside the define's array. e.g. define(['b', 'c', 'e.js', 'f.js']... ).  Does order still apply to those traditional scripts?  From my limited testing, it doesn't seem to have any effect, meaning e.js and f.js's loding order isn't preserved.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Since regular scripts don't use `define`, which can be used as a "callback" to tell RequireJS that a module is actually loaded, there is probably no straightforward way for RequireJS to tell when a regular script is loaded (though I don't know if it attempts this by using load events of `<script>` elements).